# Can I detect whether LaTeX is in vertical mode?

Tags: floats, conditionals

I am writing a command that creates a margin paragraph. This requires that this command is only used in vertical mode, which is fine. If the command is used in a float, LaTeX gives a "not in outer par mode" error, which is not very friendly. Is there a way to detect whether LaTeX is currently in vertical mode, so that I can write something helpful for the user?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `\ifvmode` switch indicates if you are in vertical mode including internal vertical mode.
There is also `\ifhmode` for the horizontal mode and `\ifinner` for "inner" mode.

See *The TeXBook*, Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros), page 209 for more details.

Note that it is sometimes required to add a `\relax` before `\ifvmode` if it is at the beginning of a macro which can be used in a location where tokens are expanded. For example in a `tabular`/`\halign` cell tokens are expanded until something unexpandable is found in order to look for a `\noalign`. In such cases the wrong mode might be still active, e.g. TeX is then in vertical mode for the first cell of a row AFAIK because the cell is not entered yet so TeX is still between rows.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to trying to duplicate the tests that LaTeX is doing, you could just locally redefine `\@parmoderr` and or `\@ehb` to something more specific to your environment.

`\@parmoderr` is defined initially as

```
    \gdef\@parmoderr{%
  \@latex@error{Not in outer par mode}\@ehb}
```

which makes the "Not in outer par mode" error and then `\@ehb` is the help text you get if you type `h` which is initially defined as

```
\gdef\@ehb{%
  You've lost some text. \space \@ehc}
\gdef\@ehc{%
  Try typing \space <return> %
  \space to proceed.\MessageBreak
  If that doesn't work, type \space X <return> \space to quit.}
```

It would be a bad idea to globally change these definitions but reasonable to change them within a specific environment.