# Custom Beamer Block has strange spacing why?

Tags: beamer, spacing, minipage

I have a custom block defined as the following! this comes from the progressbar theme from http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php

```
\newdimen\lengthone
\newcommand{\defblock}[1][]{
  \defbeamertemplate*{block \ifx#1\@empty\else#1\space\fi begin}{progressbar theme}
  {     
        %\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \lengthone=\textwidth
    \advance\lengthone by -4mm
    \setbox\progressbar@blockbox=\hbox to 1\textwidth\bgroup\vbox\bgroup
        \vskip-0.25\baselineskip
        \raggedright
        \hspace{-2.4mm}
    \begin{minipage}{\lengthone} 
        \ifx\insertblocktitle\@empty
        \else
        {\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title\ifx#1\@empty\else\space#1\fi}\insertblocktitle}\\[-0.3cm]% Just to be "babel-safe" 
        \tikz\draw[fg!20!bg] (0, 0) -- (\lengthone, 0);\par
        %\vspace{-2mm}
        \fi
        \par
        \usebeamerfont{block body\ifx#1\@empty\else\space#1\fi}
        \ifx\insertblocktitle\@empty\else\global\let\itemize=\progressbar@itemize\fi  
        %\vphantom{y}
        }

  \defbeamertemplate*{block \ifx#1\@empty\else#1\space\fi end}{progressbar theme}
  {
    \vphantom{y}
    \global\let\itemize=\progressbar@tempitemize
    \end{minipage}
    \vskip-0.25\baselineskip\egroup\egroup
    \progressbar@boxwidth=\wd\progressbar@blockbox
    %\advance\progressbar@boxwidth by 0.5\baselineskip
    %\advance\progressbar@boxwidth by 5mm
    \progressbar@boxheight=\ht\progressbar@blockbox
    \advance\progressbar@boxheight by \dp\progressbar@blockbox
    {
     \parbox[t]{0cm}{
      \usebeamercolor{block body\ifx#1\@empty\else\space#1\fi}
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]{\draw[draw=fg!20!bg,fill=bg, rounded corners=2pt] (0, 0) rectangle (\progressbar@boxwidth, \progressbar@boxheight);} 
    }
    }
  {
    \parbox[t]{0cm}{
      \vskip0.5\baselineskip
      \hfill{\box\progressbar@blockbox}\hfill
    }
   }
  }
}

\defblock
```

When I make a frame in beamer with three identical Blocks in a Minipage like this the following comes out, that the first box looks completely wrong and the follwing look right with the right spacing... Does anybody see what can cause this strange effect?

```
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Ball on Curve}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
        \item<2-> Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: I've no answer, but I noticed a big error in the first block of macros: the tests `\ifx#1\@empty` are *all* wrong. It doesn't influence your setting, as you call `\defblock` without an optional argument, but `\defblock[aachen]` would result in `\defbeamertemplate*{block chen begin}` which is clearly unwanted. However, a MWE is needed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be reproduced without all the extra definitions, so it's not dependent on the particular theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Ball on Curve}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen, the vertical spacing between the block title and the block body in the first block is less than the corresponding space in the other two blocks. Adding `\leavevmode` before the first `flushright` environment (or suppressing the `t` option for the frame) solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Ball on Curve}
\leavevmode
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Frage und Ziel}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Scheibe als \emph{ungebundenes} System formulieren.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bhut why is this command needed? How do we know latex is in vertical or horizontal mode?

Comment: @Gabriel You have `\ifvmode` and `\ifhmode` to test if LaTeX is in vertical or horizontal mode, respectively (See, for example, [Can I detect whether LaTeX is in vertical mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56727/3954) and also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13182/3954)); at the beginning of a frame, LaTeX is in vertical mode. By the way, since my answer seems to have solved your problem, please consider accepting it; in case of doubt please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).