# Macro with \marginpar only when in outer mode (loses float)

Tags: marginpar

Related to
[Can I detect whether LaTeX is in vertical mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/can-i-detect-whether-latex-is-in-vertical-mode)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\wm}{%
  \ifinner INNER \else OUTER\fi
  MODE
}

\newcommand{\mm}{%
  (trying margin par)\ifinner(no margin par)\else\marginpar{yes marginpar}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \caption{Table}
  \wm
  ...
  \mm
  ---
\end{table}

\bigskip

Text: \wm

MPAR: \mm

\end{document}
```

This informs me that my float is lost.  the output is

[image: output]

so how do I write a macro that sets a marginpar only when it is allowed to do so, and does not have the little side effects here (i.e., should have said "(no margin par)" and not give a lost float error)?

PS: When it works, [\marginpar trick: not considered as float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123995/marginpar-trick-not-considered-as-float) is pretty neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your table `\wm` is executed in vertical mode at the start of the float box, but as that's a box not the main vertical list that is inner v mode but you then typeset `INNER MODE ... (trying margin par)` which starts a paragraph, so you are in outer h mode so the test in `\mn` is false so it attempts a marginpar which fails.

You want to test for being in outer h mode in a paragraph that was started from outer v mode for which there isn't a direct test. You would probably need to keep track of paragraph starts "by hand" throughout the document.

Comment: way over my head...is there an idiot-proof (idiot=me) way to put marginpars into floats like tables and figures?  Redefining `\gdef\@parmoderr{\@latex@error{Not in outer par mode}\@ehb}` seems a bit drastic, too...

Comment: @ivoWelch you can't use marginpars in a box, just as you can't use figures in a box, you could do `\hspace*{\fill}\rlap{\smash{\hspace{\marginparsep}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{some text}}}`

Comment: is there a way at least to detect whether a marginpar is not allowed and would result in an error?

Comment: @ivoWelch  you can test for a few places it will definitely fail, but basically no.